# How to check that the H2 DataBase is Fully not corrupted?

Tags: h2

H2 Database is not very stable (But very Fast wich is very good for DEV), especialy during the developpement process, i hope that the number of corruption is du to the immediat shutdown of the Server (during debuging).

How to ensure that a H2 DataBase is not corrupted?

In order garant that a backup is good.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to check if everything is OK is to create a SQL script from the database, using the `SCRIPT` statement. If that works, then the data is fully readable. The index data might still be corrupt, but indexes can be re-created.

Another option is to always backup the data in the form of a SQL script. This will make a separate check unnecessary; but backup is a bit slower and can't be done online (while updates are happening).

By the way: if a database file gets corrupt, it's due to misconfiguration or wrong usage (H2 supports disabling the transaction log), due to hardware failure, or due to a bug in the database engine itself.

Comment: Thank you, I think that a validation method will be a very good feature, for exemple Firebird calculates checksum for every written transaction, wich garant that the file db is good